# Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI is not working on IOS only

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

we have migrated a worklight 6.1 application t IBM mobilefirst 7.0 platform and  all the functionalities working as expected on the android environment, but in ios we are facing an issue: there is a function called "quick receipt". on click on a button the device camera opens and a photo is taken. The problem is that the photo is not displaying - it returns complete blank page this issue on ios device only but not on Android device.
Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI is not working on IOS.

for security reason we wont share the code. here is similar prototype code.

html

```
    <div><img alt="QuickReceipts" src="resources/img/camera.png" onclick="imgCapture();"</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    imgCapture: function (){

    navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onSuccess, this.onFail,{quality:80,destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, targetWidth:600,targetHeight:1050}
    },
    onSuccess:function(imgData)
    {
    // applying the css and displaying the img
  $("#imgReceipt").attr("src","data:image/jpeg;base64," +imgData);
  $("#imgReceipt").css("display", "block");
    }
    onFail:function(imgData){
    // failure msg
    }
```

Comment: Please mention the exact build number of MobileFirst 7.0 that you're using. Also provide a sample project that uses only the code that does not work so the error could be debugged.

Comment: MFP version 7.0.0.00-20150907-1450 .  Its enterprise application for security reason we wont share the code out side of organization .

Comment: Are the typos in your code snippet also in your own code? "onSucces".

Comment: please make your comment more clear .

Comment: Your success call back function -

onSucces:function(imgData).    Notice the missing 's' in 'onSucces'.

This is what Idan asked

Comment: ya i correct it .still same issue on ios only .what i created sample prototype of coding structure because its enterprise app code is not shareable outside

Comment: This  issue may be  "xcode build time error" .there are any file missing or enter the file content missing check out , carefully.

Comment: Build got success and i tested with iPhone and ipad device same issue .but same code working properly on android devices.its hybrid application

Comment: well , your problem is the photo is not displaying ? check out this http://www.telerik.com/forums/ios-cordova-3-5-0-camera-getpicture-targetwidth-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion is to attempt to code change as mentioned by Nazmul: http://www.telerik.com/forums/ios-cordova-3-5-0-camera-getpicture-targetwidth-issue.

Another suggestion is to upgrade to the latest 7.1 iFix from IBM Fix Central which contains several Cordova corrections and may address your issue.

If your issue is not resolved still, I suggest to open an IBM PMR (support ticket).

Comment: Thanks .i resolved the issue by Nazmul's  suggestion.